# Mark Files in SourceSafe as Obsolete

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I've recently migrated code off of a limping SourceSafe database to a fresh SourceSafe database. We're maintaining the old database to keep our version history, but I'd like to mark those files as obsolete, so other programmers don't get confused as to which version to use.

Does SourceSafe support any feature that lets me flag files as obsolete but keep them in the database?

Comment: (Off-topic: SourceSafe _itself_ is obsolete. If it's an option, consider migrating to a different version control system, e.g. Subversion. There are good Visual Studio integration add-ins available for that one, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You yourself, check all of the files out of the old source safe,
and they will come and ask you to check them back in.
At that point you can educate them.

Comment: I like this approach, but it's problematic after I'm no longer working on that project.

Answer (score 0):

delete option will do this for you. The file (and its) revision histories will remain in version reporitory but file itself wont be visible from current version onwards